# function pointer from one class to member function of any class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having difficulties defining a function pointer that can point to any member function (not just member functions for the specified class).

For instance, C++ forces me to specify the class that a function pointer to a member function would point to:

```
typedef void (Foo::*MyFunctionPointerTypeName)(int);
```

but what if the class member function that this function pointer is going to point to isn't in `Foo`? How then would I write this, or what alternative approach could I use?

---

**Update:** For anyone looking for a quick answer on how to accomplish this with a C++11  `std::function` (as tutorials on the subject seem to assume alot of the reader):

Definition (from within `Foo`):

```
std::function<void(int)> _fun;
```

Binding (from any class):

```
objFoo->_fun = std::bind(&SomeOtherClass::memberFunction, 
    this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Calling it (from within `Foo`)

```
if(_fun != nullptr) _fun(42);
```

If your function has no parameters, you can remove `std::placeholders::_1`. And if your function has two parameters you'll need to **also add** `std::placeholders::_2` as a parameter to `std::bind`. Similarly for three parameters, four parameters, etc.

Comment: In what circumstances do you want to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write a member pointer that could point to a member of *any* class. Remember: one of the arguments of a member pointer is the class instance itself. And pointers are typed, so the type of its arguments is very much a part of the pointer's type.

You *can* use `std::function` however, which can store all sorts of callables. How you would actually call it (ie: what parameters you give it) depends on your needs, as you haven't explained what you're trying to do.

Comment: `one of the arguments of a member pointer is the class instance itself`. Technically incorrect. Instead its the `this` pointer or pointer to the object in question.

Comment: Having read [Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) just now, I agree. It isn't possible to do this with a function pointer. I've got a working solution with std::function (since I'm using C++11), but I wish a function pointer would have worked (for sake of simplicity).

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    int F0()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct Baz : public Foo
{
    int F1()
    {
        return 1;
    }    
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int (Bar::*pF0)() = &Bar::F0;
    int (Baz::*pF1)() = &Baz::F1;
    int (Foo::*pointer1)() = static_cast<int (Foo::*)()>(pF0);
    int (Foo::*pointer2)() = static_cast<int (Foo::*)()>(pF1);

    Bar r;
    Baz z;

    // Pointer to Foo member function calling Bar member function        
    std::cout << (r.*pointer1)() << '\n';
    // Pointer to Foo member function calling Baz member function
    std::cout << (z.*pointer2)() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/iDBM98):

```
0
1
```

Hope it helps.